# Converting String into date format in JS

Tags: javascript

I need to covert the string which contains date and time looks like this

`"27-JAN-15 08.30.00.000000 AM"`

When I use `new Date("27-JAN-15 08.30.00.000000 AM")` I get error as`Invalid Date`.

Please do help.

Thanks

Comment: you want both date and time? or just date?

Comment: *"When I use new Date("27-JAN-15 08.30.00.000000 AM") I get error asInvalid Date."* Right. Because there's nothing whatsoever that claims that the `Date` constructor can parse that format. So *you* have to. Once you give it a try, if you run into trouble, ask a specific question about the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dateVal = "27-JAN-15 08.30.00.000000 AM";
console.log(new Date(dateVal.split(".").join(":")));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDate = function(dateString) {
    var dateString = dateString || "27-JAN-15 08.30.00.000000 AM" // An example
    var newDate = new Date(dateString.split(" ")[0]);
    var hours = dateString.split(" ")[2]==="AM" ? dateString.split(" ")[1].split(".")[0] : parseInt(dateString.split(" ")[1].split(".")[0], 10) + 12;
    newDate.setHours(hours);
    newDate.setMinutes(dateString.split(" ")[1].split(".")[1]);
    newDate.setSeconds(dateString.split(" ")[1].split(".")[2]);
    newDate.setMilliseconds(dateString.split(" ")[1].split(".")[3]);
    return newDate;
}
```

Comment: This will probably work, but it would be cleaner to split only once and store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Manual parsing is the way to go.

`"27-JAN-15 08.30.00.000000 AM"`

First `split` you string at the "spaces", giving you

`"27-JAN-15"`

`"08.30.00.000000"`

`"AM"`

Now you can take the date part and `split` at the `-`, giving you

`"27"`

`"JAN"`

`"15"`

Now you can convert the month by using an `object` as a lookup table to give you a numeric value.

So `JAN` will give you `0`, you now have

`"27"`

`"0"`

`"15"`

The year part is now ambiguous, `Date` will take values from 0 to 99 and map to the years 1900 to 1999. So you will need to decide how you are going to deal with this based on your data.

Now the last 2 strings, you have

`"08.30.00.000000"`

`"AM"`

The `"AM"` or `"PM"` can be ignored as the time is in 24 hour format, so now `split` the time string at `.`, giving you

`"08"`

`"30"`

`"00"`

`"000000"`

The `Date` constructor only handles and accuracy of milliseconds, so you could take the `"000000"` and `slice` the first 3 digits, giving you

`"000"`

Now take all the parts that you have manually parsed and use them with the `date` constructor

`new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]]);`

so,

`new Date("15", "0", "27", "08", "30", "00", "000");`

You will now have a javascript local `date` object, without cross browser `parse` inconsistencies.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

If your date is UTC then you may want to use

`Date.UTC()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC